# Parsing a file ,extract contents and perform operation on extracted contents

Tags: file-io, sed

I have an HTML file with plenty of contents in it. I want to extract specific lines from it.

Ex:
I want to extract multiple lines which has this specific content `"class="red"`

```
&lt;tr class="even"&gt;&lt;td&gt;***FRQ\AUTO\spml-hlr601\FC122_005036_PDPContext\DB8PD073\BulkPDPModreq***&lt;/a&gt;&lt;td align='center' **class="red"**&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
```

Once i extract this line, i would want this string: `FRQ\AUTO\spml-hlr601\FC122_005036_PDPContext\DB8PD073\BulkPDPModreq`.

This string is a directory name and i would want to copy the contents from this directory to specific directory (/home/user)

I would want to do this operation for all the occurences of the lines which have the text `"class=red"`

Would like to do this with sed.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the sample you provided. I also assumed that the `*` part of the interesting string is not really part of your input file, but if it is this will need tweaking:

```
$ cat foo.html
foo
<tr class="even"><td>FRQ\AUTO\spml-hlr601\FC122_005036_PDPContext\DB8PD073\BulkPDPModreq1</a><td align='center' class="red"></tr>
<tr class="even"><td>FRQ\AUTO\spml-hlr601\FC122_005036_PDPContext\DB8PD073\BulkPDPModreq2</a><td align='center' class="red"></tr>
bar
<tr class="even"><td>FRQ\AUTO\spml-hlr601\FC122_005036_PDPContext\DB8PD073\BulkPDPModreq3</a><td align='center' class="red"></tr>
<tr class="even"><td>FRQ\AUTO\spml-hlr601\FC122_005036_PDPContext\DB8PD073\BulkPDPModreq4</a><td align='center' class="red"></tr>
quux
```

.

```
$ grep 'class="red"' foo.html \
    | sed 's#.*<td>##g;s#</a>.*##g;s#\\#/#g' \
    | xargs -I% echo cp -r /home/hlrci/%/* /home/hlrci/CopyReq/
cp -r /home/hlrci/FRQ/AUTO/spml-hlr601/FC122_005036_PDPContext/DB8PD073/BulkPDPModreq1/* /home/hlrci/CopyReq/
cp -r /home/hlrci/FRQ/AUTO/spml-hlr601/FC122_005036_PDPContext/DB8PD073/BulkPDPModreq2/* /home/hlrci/CopyReq/
cp -r /home/hlrci/FRQ/AUTO/spml-hlr601/FC122_005036_PDPContext/DB8PD073/BulkPDPModreq3/* /home/hlrci/CopyReq/
cp -r /home/hlrci/FRQ/AUTO/spml-hlr601/FC122_005036_PDPContext/DB8PD073/BulkPDPModreq4/* /home/hlrci/CopyReq/
```

This searches for `class="red"` in `foo.html` (`grep`), removes everything up to and including `<td>` and everything starting from and including `</a>` on each line (`sed`), reads each line and  crafts a `cp` command around it to copy your files. Depending on the input file and your situation and preference you might have/want to

- adapt the `sed` regex or make it more specific
- use something else than `cp` to actually copy your stuff (`tar`, `cpio`, `rsync`, ...)

Dryrun with `echo` and if you are happy with the output remove the `echo` and rerun.

Comment: I used the following command : grep 'class=\"red\"' samp.html  | sed sed 's#.*<td>##g;s#</a>.*##g' |  xargs -I% echo cp -r /home/hlrci/%/* /home/hlrci/CopyReq/ 
The echo is "cp -r /home/hlrci/FRQAUTOspml-hlr601FC122_005036_PDPContextDB8PD073BulkPDPModreqDB8PD073/* /home/hlrci/CopyReq/
Note: I am losing the "\" characters in the cp command. I want to convert "\" into "/" and preserve them. how do i achieve it. Also "please provide me links to know about "s#" command

Comment: See my edit. The `s` command is explained [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) in the `sed` manual, but you might also find [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1) useful.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, I went through these tutorials, but I dont see any specific examples of "s#", "#g". How does "#" work here, wanted to get some information on it.

Comment: `sed` allows you to use a delimiter of your choice, so `s/question/sentence/` is the same as `s#question#sentence#`. It is a matter of preference, and depending on the strings you are substituting it can make life easier. If you use `/` as delimiter but your string also contains `/` you would have to escape it, with a different character you can avoid this and it is easier on the eye. Apologies for not mentioning this in the first place.